# Replace current top activity from intent

Tags: android, notifications

In my Android app I send Notification like that:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MyActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, myActivityId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageSubtitle)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).getNotification();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(myActivityId, n);
```

Now when I tap on notification I go to MyActivity activity. I usualy send couple notification at once. When I tap on first notification and then immediately tap on second notification I will have 2 views in my views stack. I mean when I tap back on my phone from second notification activity I'm back to first notification activity. I want to second notification activity replace first notifitaction activity that when I tap back I go to view which was displayed before I started taping on notifications. How can I do that?

Comment: see Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_*

Comment: Yeah, I try to use them but none of them helped me :(

Comment: so read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html